# Visual hint for the location of hidden comments

Tags: feature-request, comments

I often come across questions/answers with lots of comments. Not all comments are shown, only a handful with the most up-votes. While I like this filtering, most of the time I click on the “show more comments” field because highly up-voted comments may depend on not shown comments.

It would be great to have a little visual hint as to where the hidden comments are located. Something like this:

[image]

Comment: This is already being discussed at [Proposed tweak to comment UI for long threads](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/235255); that's a Stack Exchange employee requesting feedback on upcoming comment thread changes. Your proposal is closely related to the [current top-voted answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/235259) there.

Comment: Ah, great. So probably my question should be deleted?

Comment: Normally, it's fine to discuss feature requests here, but with that post being the current focus, this one does look redundant. Chances are that whatever the devs come up make this one obsolete sooner or later.

Comment: And clicking the "1 hidden comment" will make that particular comment appear?

Comment: @TheGuywithTheHat No, some other, random comment ;V

Comment: @BartoszKP Ah, good. Glad to see _someone_ here has some sense.

Comment: I'd much prefer to see this behaviour disabled completely so I always see all the comments, in fact I'd rather have all comments hidden by default than what we currently have. There's nothing worse than reading an interesting discussion, to get to the end and realise you've missed some of it. The only comments I don't want to read, are the ones that will get flagged and removed.

Comment: I agree with bryan, the comments seem to get mixed up and you end up with a different context.  Show the comments (all of them) and let me read the comments as if it were a book - in the order they came in.